# SQL GROUP_CONCAT + SUM + AVG

Tags: sql, mysql, sum, group-concat, average

```
SELECT *,
       Group_concat(rating) AS rating_total,
       Sum(rating_total)    AS rating_sum,
       Avg(rating_sum)      AS rating_avg
FROM   ratings
GROUP  BY pid
```

For some reason the sum and average don't execute....how do you make this statement work?

Answer (score 5):

Because of the way that SQL compiles the queries (I assume MySQL since you're using GROUP_CONCAT), you cannot reference aliased column names before the order by clause.  The SUM and AVG functions *are not procedural*.  They are done in parallel.  Which means that they can't be dependent.

Secondly, GROUP_CONCAT returns a string, not a number.  How to you hope to SUM/AVG that?  Just SUM and AVG the rating column in and of itself.

Now, given this, you could do:

```
SELECT
    pid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(rating) AS rating_total,
    SUM(rating) as rating_sum,
    AVG(rating) as rating_avg
FROM
    rating
GROUP BY
    pid
```

This should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, but it might be the * in a GROUP BY query.

Comment: Good catch.  I blindly copied OP's rows without thinking about it. Changed, so thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT returns a string, concatenating all the selected valuse. Then, you are trying to sum that string and then you are trying to get the average of the sum.

I think you need to use SUM and AVG upon values from the table, not the result of concatenation.